# Regex not working - minimum 1 uppercase, minimum 3 lowercase, minimum 1 special character from the defined group (more in description)

Tags: php, regex, passwords

I need to create a regular expression with the next demands: Password need to have at least 8 characters and maximum 12 characters, at least 1 uppercase, at least 3 lowercase, at least 1 digit and at least 1 special character from the group (#*.!?$), without parentheses. The first character needs to be an uppercase or lowercase letter. Two consecutive same characters must not appear in the password.
I made this, but it doesn't work:

```
^(?=.{8,12}$)(([a-z]|[A-Z])(?=.*\d){1,}(?=.*[a-z]){3,}(?=.*[A-Z]){1,}(?=.*[!.?*$#])\2?(?!\2))+$
```

I tried to test it with Abcd123!, but it doesn't work. Can anyone explain where did I make a mistake, and what I actually did here?

Comment: Please, let people choose their password.  Eventually make 20 character at least.

Comment: `20 character at least`  - that should be the min, with 5 of each type ... J/P

Comment: My task requires that the password length should be between 8 and 12 characters long, it's not my choice.

Comment: You should give [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48345922/3600709) a good read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a quantifier like `{1,}` for the lookahead which is not correct.

I think you meant to use the lookaheads like this:

```
^(?=.{8,12}$)(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){3})(?=[^\s#*.!?$]*[#*.!?$])(?!.*(.)\1)(?:[a-z]|[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9#*.!?$,]+$
```

About the pattern

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?=.{8,12}$)` Assert lenght 8 - 12
- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` Assert an uppercase char
- `(?=\D*\d)` Assert a digit
- `(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){3})` Assert 3 lowercase chars
- `(?=[^\s#*.!?$]*[#*.!?$])` Assert special char
- `(?!.*(.)\1)` Assert not 2 consecutive chars
- `(?:[a-z]|[A-Z])` Start with upper or lowercase char
- `[a-zA-Z0-9#*.!?$,]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed in the character class
- `$` Assert end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PZT0Z8/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/Z3rej)

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. At first I tried the simplest regex with the length constraint and using uppercase, lowercase and digits and it worked, but it would be just 20% of the regex I need.

Comment: Which matches do not work? And what should the other 80%  match? The lookaheads in the pattern match your requirements. You could add the the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9#*.!?$,]+` what  you want to allow to match.

Comment: The regex you provided does not work, I don't understand why. What you wrote is completely what I need, it just probably needs some modifications in order to work. Those 20% were what I previously made, some basic regex.

Comment: This is the code that worked 
`
$uppercase = preg_match('@[A-Z]@', $pass); 
$lowercase = preg_match('@[a-z]@', $pass); 
$number = preg_match('@[0-9]@', $pass); 
`
and this is what doesn't work 
`
$pattern = '/^(?=.{8,12}$)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=(?:.*[a-z]))(?=.*[#*.!?$])(?!.*(.)\1)(?:[a-z]|[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9#*.!?$,]+$/'; 
$regex = preg_match($pattern, $pass);
`

Comment: @MilošMladenović Sorry for my late response. I have created 2 examples where the pattern works for me in php. See https://3v4l.org/5Z8db Can you let me know if those also work for you?

Comment: Everything is ok, thanks a lot for your help! I didn't answer right away because I was trying to find an error in my code. Your first regex is also good (I checked it via online regex validator), but for some reason preg_match in my code always returns 0, so it does not enter if conditional and of course does not write anything into database. My logic looks like this:

Comment: I will mark your first answer. If you could see where have I mistaken in logic, it would be of great help:
    $regex = preg_match('/^(?=.{8,12}$)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=(?:.*[a-z]){3})(?=.*[#*.!?$])(?!.*(.)\1)(?:[a-z]|[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9#*.!?$,]+$/m', $pass);
    if($regex) {// write into database};

Comment: @MilošMladenović This is an example using your code and from what I can see is that is works https://3v4l.org/9vrDk Do you have an example of a string for which it fails?

Comment: I tried with "Abcd1234!", for example. Can md5 function cause a trouble?

Comment: I found an error: I shouldn't put $_POST into md5 function because it generates a lot of characters which do not match with my constraint od 12 characters. I just used md5 function when writing into database and it worked.@The fourth bird, once again, thanks a lot for your help!